# Rebuilding existing flash project with Flex

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript

I'm not a flash developer.

We paid a developer to build us an app. It is nearly perfect, but a few things in the actionscript need tweaking (purely the values of some URL's for action when buttons are clicked.)

I believe I need to rebuild the project to pull this information through.

I have installed the Flash SDK, but when I do

```
mxmlc Main.as
```

I get a bunch of errors about missing dependencies.

I believe he has sent me the full source. Do I need to install all of the dependencies to get this to work? I'm tempted to just go in and make the changes in a hex editor..

Comment: Is there an .fla file? If so, it was built using the [Flash Authoring Tool](http://www.adobe.com/products/flash/whatisflash/), and you'll need to install that to build it

Comment: Yep, I have an .fla. I will install that and report back.

EDIT: Is there an open source alternative? I'm on linux..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to use the Flash Authoring tool (current version is Flash CS5), unfortunately there's no open source alternative for compiling `FLA` files.

Comment: I can't find results for "Flash Authoring Tool". Is FlashBuilder what I'm after?

Comment: No, it's **Flash CS5** at the moment.

Comment: You may need to be aware of the class path that the app uses, there's a useful discussion [here](http://www.actionscript.org/forums/showthread.php3?t=156770)